# React-Native-Maps Marker Array in Child Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm currently learning react-native and react-native-maps (using typescript ES6) and I'm having some issues rendering markers in that they just don't appear. I've attempted to separate my logic into components that make's sense to me but I'm wondering if this is the reason I can't get them to render.

What I have is the following:

**Main Map Component**

```
<MapView style={styles.map}
         region={this.props.region}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         followsUserLocation={false}>
    <View>
        <SearchCircle />
        <MarkerList />
    <View>
 <MapView>
```

**SearchCircle**

The SearchCircle works perfectly and the code contains:

```
import { Circle } from 'react-native-maps';

...

class SearchCircle extends React.Component<SearchProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Circle center={this.props.user.location}
                    radius={this.props.map.searchRadius}
                    fillColor={'rgba(230,238,255,0.5)'}
                    strokeColor={'#1A66FF'}
                    strokeWidth={1} />
        );
    }
}
```

**MarkerList** - **ISSUE**

The MarkerList is the component that does not render correctly. It contains:

```
class MarkerList extends React.Component<MarkerListProps> {

    // render our contacts
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.props.markerlist[0] != undefined && this.props.markerList.map((marker, index) => (
                    this.renderMarker( marker, index )
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderMarker( marker: MarkerEntry, index: number ) {
        return (
            <View key={index}>
                <Marker coordinate={marker.location} title={marker.title} />
                <Text>{'Lat: ' + marker.location.latitude + ', Long: ' + marker.location.longitude}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The MarkerList component does call render() when the state updates (when I update the markers locations) BUT only the **Text** element renders/updates correctly. The Lat/Lng is displayed correctly on my screen however the **Marker** element does not appear at all. The *markerlist* property for the MarkerList component is a list of type *MarkerEntry* which contains the following:

```
interface MarkerEntry {
    title: string
    location: LatLng
}
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get any markers to render from this array. If I statically define markers then everything works just fine but with my property array list **map** they never render.

**Static Example that works**

```
class MarkerList extends React.Component<MarkerListProps> {

    // render our contacts
    render() {

        let marker = {
            id: 'Test',
            location: {
                latitude: -31.970097415447232,
                longitude: 115.92362245895334
            }
        };

        let markerArray: any[] = [];
        markerArray.push( marker );

        return (
            <View>
                {markerArray[0] != undefined && markerArray.map((c, index) => (
                    <Marker key={index} coordinate={c.location} title={c.id} />
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to assist. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing something about how react-native **should** be structured for this to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So I've managed to solve my problem and thought I'd leave my final solution here for anyone else that needs it. The issues were with how I was defining the **MapView** and also with how I was returning the **map** results.

**Map Component**

For the main map component I had to remove the child <View> entry I had defined.

**Before**

```
<MapView style={styles.map}
         region={this.props.region}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         followsUserLocation={false}>
    <View>**
        <SearchCircle />
        <MarkerList />
    <View>
 <MapView>
```

**After**

```
<MapView style={styles.map}
         region={this.props.region}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         followsUserLocation={false}>
    <SearchCircle />
    <MarkerList />
 <MapView>
```

**MarkerList**

The second part I had to change was the render function and it's syntax in the render function.

**Before**

```
class MarkerList extends React.Component<MarkerListProps> {
    // render our contacts
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.props.markerlist[0] != undefined && this.props.markerList.map((marker, index) => (
                    this.renderMarker( marker, index )
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderMarker( marker: MarkerEntry, index: number ) {
        return (
            <View key={index}>
                <Marker coordinate={marker.location} title={marker.title} />
                <Text>{'Lat: ' + marker.location.latitude + ', Long: ' + marker.location.longitude}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**After**

Note the additional return statements outside and inside the map call and the removal of the <View> element.

```
class MarkerList extends React.Component<MarkerListProps> {
    // render our contacts
    render() {
        return this.props.markerList.map((marker, index) => {
            return( this.renderMarker( marker, index ));
        });
    }

    renderMarker( marker: MarkerEntry index: number)  {
        return (
            <View key={index}>
                <Marker coordinate={marker.location} title={marker.title} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```